# Python - Join list of lists with list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have python script that reads a .txt. file and appends items to a two different lists:

//Edit: fragment of my input file:
[image]

```
list_data_type = [
  ['void'], ['uint8'], 
  [['uint8'], ['uint32']], ['void'], 
  ['void'], ['void'], ['void']
]

list_arg_parameter = [
  [None], ['f_MbistTestType_u8'], 
  ['f_MbistTestType_u8', 'f_chip_id_u32'], [None], 
  [None], [None], [None]
]
```

I want to join corresponding items of both list, which I know can be done with zip function, but I want to print the result of both lists in a .csv file, and I want that those two list with 2 elements would be written into same slot and it would look like this:

```
file_name_1;function_name_1; void (None)
file_name_1;function_name_2; uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8
file_name_1;function_name_3; uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8, uint32 f_chip_id_u32
```

Also I don't want any "[]" or "''" signs. Right now I tried to convert both lists to a string, strip all unnecessary brackets, convert those strings back to list via this function:

```
def Convert(string):
li = list(string.split(" "))
return li
```

And then use simple for loop to make pair of elements:

```
for elements in zip(list_data_type_strpd, list_arg_parameter_strpd): 
    list_func_arg_combined.append(' '.join(elements))
```

But the result looks like this:

```
'void '
'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8'
'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8'
'uint32 f_chip_id_32'
'void '
'void '
'void '
'void '
```

And I would like it, like this:

```
'void '
'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8'
'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8, uint32 f_chip_id_32'
'void '
'void '
'void '
'void '
```

Maybe I turn those list to string unnecessarily? Maybe there is a easier way to accomplish my goal? Any help, critique or different solutions are welcome.

Comment: can you add the code for reading the file and also ass the sample input

Comment: I can, but my input file is kinda specific. It's is parsed C file via a python module I found online. This input file is in .txt format, but what it really is a big list with lots of parameters. My goal is to gather only those that matter to me and save it in a .csv format. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (one level to merge the two lists, one level to `zip` the sublists, one level to extract the strings from the lowest level of list):

```
out = [', '.join([' '.join([z[0] if isinstance(z, list) else z for z in y])
                  if y[1] else y[0]
                  for y in (zip(*x))])
       for x in zip(list_data_type, list_arg_parameter)]
```

Output:

```
['void',
 'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8',
 'uint8 f_MbistTestType_u8, uint32 f_chip_id_u32',
 'void',
 'void',
 'void',
 'void']
```

Comment: Ok, seems that Your solution works ;) . Thank You for that, but what about scalability. WiIl it work in case I would like to join 3 pairs in one place? Or if there would be more than one list with two elements? I'm sorry to ask, but I don;t fully understand structure of this code, would appreciate if You would give a quick explanation to every line. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to print the lines according to how you want them:

```py
for data_types, arg_parameters in zip(list_data_type, list_arg_parameter):
    print_line = ""
    for data_type, arg_parameter in zip(data_types, arg_parameters):
        if print_line:
            print_line += ", "
        # You could extract the next line to the `convert` function if you wish to do so
        print_data_type = str(data_type).lstrip("['").rstrip("]'")
        print_line += f"{print_data_type} {arg_parameter}"
    print(print_line)
```

However, I think there's an error in how `list_data_type` is initialised. Specifically, the 3rd element in `list_data_type` should be a list of strings, not a list of lists. Specifically,

```py
# This requires us to have a `hacky` convert function
list_data_type = [
  ['void'], ['uint8'], 
  [['uint8'], ['uint32']], ['void'], 
  ['void'], ['void'], ['void']
]
# The proper one would be a list of strings instead
list_data_type = [
  ['void'], ['uint8'], 
  ['uint8', 'uint32'], ['void'],  # Note the difference in this line
  ['void'], ['void'], ['void']
]
```

Since you mentioned that you have a python script that reads a txt file and initialises `list_data_type`, you might want to fix that. Once that is fixed, you can remove the `convert` function and it will print your data in your output nicely.

Comment: There is no error, it is written in my input file like this. Please see picture I just added of my input file.